# Question about loops and continue

Tags: javascript, loops

So is this actually naming the loop to `nextLoop`? So when it says `continue nextLoop`, does it go back to the top right away?

```
   var total = 0;
        nextLoop:
        for ( var i = 0; i < 7; ++i ) {
            for ( var j = 0; j < 6 ; ++j ) {
                if ( i < 5 )
                continue nextLoop;
                total++;
                }
            total++;
        }
    total++;
    document.write( total );
```

**Edit:**

Is that naming the loop `nextLoop:`? If so, what else can you name? Any references to why naming stuff can be useful?

Comment: I never know how to answer questions like this. The answer is "Yes, you're exactly right", but that seems hardly worth a post.

Comment: Updated my answer to answer your edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. This is useful for when you have a loop nested inside another loop and you want to continue the *outer* loop. [Here's a page on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Loop_Statements/continue_Statement) about it. So in your case, during the `i = 2` loop if, from within the `j` loop, you say `continue nextLoop`, it'll jump out of the `j` loop, do the `i` increment, and continue with `i = 3`.

Using `continue` with labels is not *usually* good practice; it can indicate that the logic needs to be refactored. But it's perfectly valid syntactically and I expect someone will chime in with an example situation where they feel it's absolutely necessary.

**Edit** Answering your edit, the label (name) of the loop is `nextLoop` (without the colon): You can label statements and then use those labels as the targets of `continue` and `break`. Check out [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) for details. The typical use is to label loops as in your example and either `continue` or `break` them, but note that `break` also applies to nested `switch` statements -- you can label them like loops and break to an outer one from within one of the inner one's cases. You can even intermix them so you can break a loop from within a switch (the label namespace is common to both).

Comment: I think that you can go without it in any case.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reference to why it can be useful!

Answer (score 1):

It does. But you should avoid it. It is a bad practice, similar to `go to`. Makes the code hard to read, understand and spaghetti like.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the expected behaviour. Take a look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_loop_control.htm)

Answer (score 0):

other languages let you break out of a selected number of inner loops,
if(!x)break 2; would continue the process at a point two steps up.

I've seen complex loops with multiple loop labels, 
and continues called to a specific  label, but I agree it can confuse the logic.

You can almost always improve the efficiency of a loop by writing it without the continue:

```
var total= 0;
nextLoop: 
for (var i = 0; i < 7; ++i ){
    for (var j = 0; j < 6 ; ++j ){
        if(i>4) total++;
    }
    total++;
}

total++;
```